# getMany Option in typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nest, typeorm

I have a repository function in typeorm which gives a collection of entity. I am trying to save this array into a variable and use it for something else. Here's what i have tried:

```
//Service 
    async createOrderProposal(createOrderProposalDto: CreateOrderProposalDto) {
        const { startDate, categories, paymentMethodId, address } = createOrderProposalDto;
        let freelancers;
        categories.forEach(async category => {
            freelancers.push(await this.freelancerRepository.getFreelancersByCategoryId(category.categoryId));
        })
        console.log(freelancers); // gives []
    }
```

Then the repository function looks something like:

```
    async getFreelancersByCategoryId(categoryId: string){
        await this.createQueryBuilder('freelancers')
            .innerJoinAndSelect('freelancers.user','user')
            .innerJoinAndSelect('user.freelancerCategories', 'categories')
            .select('freelancers')
            .where('categories.category_id = :categoryId', {categoryId})
            .getMany()
}
```

Logging this repository function gives me the correct entities but i am unable to store it in a variable in service. What am i doing wrong??

Comment: ```.forEach(...)``` expects a **synchronous function** and won't do anything with the return value. It just calls the function and on to the next. ```for...of``` will actually await on the result of the execution of the function. See [Why does async/await in a .forEach not actually await?](https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await) for more information.
Therefore, the solution is to change from ```categories.forEach(async category => {...})``` to ```for (const category of categories) {...}```.

Comment: Moreover, can you optimize the selection into a single *query*? As far as I can see from your code you can.